# Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for UserService (?)

Tags: angular, typescript

After my application was compiled, I am getting the following error in the console:

> `Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for UserService (?)`

I don't know where else to look. `@Injectable()` is present for the `UserService`

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Observable} from "rxjs";
import {UserModel} from "../../model/user.model";
import {environment} from "../../../environments/environment";
import {HttpClient} from "@angular/common/http";


@Injectable()
export class UserService {

  constructor(
    private _http: HttpClient
  ) {
  }

  getMe(): Observable<UserModel> {
    return this._http.get<UserModel>(environment.adminApiUrl + '/me');
  }
}
```

and the `app.module.ts` should contain all relevant modules:

```
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {Injector, NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {AppComponent} from './app.component';
import {AppRouting} from "./app.routing";
import {BrowserAnimationsModule} from "@angular/platform-browser/animations";
import {LoggerModule, NgxLoggerLevel} from "ngx-logger";
import {environment} from "../environments/environment";
import {AuthGuard} from "./service/guard/auth.guard";
import {UserService} from "./api/service/user.service";
import {CommonModule} from "@angular/common";
import {setAppInjector} from "./app-injector";
import {HttpClientModule} from "@angular/common/http";

const ApiServices = [
  UserService
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    HttpClientModule,

    AppRouting,

    // Logging
    LoggerModule.forRoot({
      serverLoggingUrl: '/',
      level: environment.production ? NgxLoggerLevel.OFF : NgxLoggerLevel.TRACE,
      serverLogLevel: NgxLoggerLevel.OFF
    }),
  ],
  providers: [
    AuthGuard,
    ApiServices
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

Still I am getting this error.

What am I missing out?

---

If I remove `private _http: HttpClient` from the constructor in `UserService`, the application works. It's as if the `Injectable()` annotation does not work in my setup.

Comment: @ChrisY Yes. see app.module.ts. Idk what's going on. Even did the `rm -rf node_modules` dance.

Comment: In which module is the `UserService` provided?

Comment: Can you try just adding `UserService` directly in the `providers`? Also, did you try restarting the app again?

Comment: @ChrisY Currently it's only provided in `app.module.ts` but it's not used anywhere yet.

Comment: @NicholasK Tried it but didn't help.

Comment: can you reproduce the issue on stackblitz ?

Comment: I think you should destructure `const ApiServices = [
  UserService
];` in the `providers` section. Like `providers: [...ApiServices]`

Comment: @Allabakash ChrisY Turns out it was [this](https://github.com/thymikee/jest-preset-angular/issues/288) issue. I never had this issue before but it works now.

Answer (score 1):

I found this issue on github: "[Angular 8: Can't resolve all parameters for Component: (?)](https://github.com/thymikee/jest-preset-angular/issues/288)"

> **Note:** I am on Angular 7

which suggest putting

```
"emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
```

inside `tsconfig.spec.json`. However, it only worked placing it in `tsconfig.json` too:

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ]
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "fullTemplateTypeCheck": true,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true
  }
}
```

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "outDir": "./out-tsc/spec",
    "types": [
      "jasmine",
      "node"
    ]
  },
  "files": [
    "src/test.ts",
    "src/polyfills.ts"
  ],
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.spec.ts",
    "src/**/*.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

Checking older projects of mine, I realized that `emitDecoratorMetadata` was always set to `true`. I created the project above running `ng new <project-name>` with

```
$ ng --version

     _                      _                 ____ _     ___
    / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
   / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
  / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
 /_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
                |___/


Angular CLI: 8.3.21
Node: 10.15.2
OS: linux x64
Angular: 
... 

Package                      Version
------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect    0.803.21
@angular-devkit/core         8.3.21
@angular-devkit/schematics   8.3.21
@schematics/angular          8.3.21
@schematics/update           0.803.21
rxjs                         6.4.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a heads up, I had the same issue when upgrading from Angular 8 to Angular 9.

The issue was with the `NGXS` state.

From this piece of code I was missing the `@Injectable` part.

```
@State<ActiveFiltersStateModel>({
  name: 'filterAdapters',
  defaults: {
    filters: {}
  }
})
@Injectable()
export class ActiveFiltersState {

  constructor() {
  }
}
```

[image: missing INJECTABLE]

> The Angular team has worked hard to ensure Ivy is as
> backwards-compatible with the previous rendering engine (“View
> Engine”) as possible. Unfortunately, some changes have to be made so
> that NGXS and Ivy can function together seamlessly.